# How to query many to many relation in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I've been using feathersjs/nodejs over postgres db via sequelize. In my db i have Users table and Events table. They are twice in relation:

```
events.belongsTo(models.users, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'creatorId',
    allowNull: false
  },
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  as: 'creator'
});

events.belongsToMany(models.users, {
  through: 'event_participants',
  as: 'participants',
  foreignKey: 'eventId',
  otherKey: 'userId'
});
models.users.belongsToMany(events, {
  through: 'event_participants',
  as: 'events'
});
```

Everything works just fine, table is created and with include im getting users inside of event as participants. Problem is querying by association. I'm trying to fetch events for current user, so I need events where creator is current user AND events where one of participants is current user. Problem is the second part 'querying where current user is one of participants'. I was expecting something like this

`'api/events?$or[0][creatorId]=currUserId&$or[1][participants][$contains]=currUserId'`

but its not working cause there is no such column as 'participants' its being included so i cant query it. So for now I'm just fetching all events and filtering them for current user in after hooks, but it just seems wrong. What is the right way to do this?

And yea I know I can get events where user is one of participants by including them into user and fetching him but problem with that is i cant sort that data all together, its being sorted separately and another problem is doin pagination on frontend.

Comment: add your query here

Comment: @Priyank what query? I said I'm fetching all the data and filtering it in after hooks, so there is no query, its just 'api/events' .. the one I thought would work is already up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying for nested associations is not part of Feathers common query syntax. In the case of Sequelize the query should be assembled according to your needs using [params.sequelize](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#associations) and includes as shown in the [feathers-sequelize associations documentation](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#associations):

```js
    // GET /my-service?name=John&include=1
    function (context) {
       if (context.params.query.include) {
          const AssociatedModel = context.app.services.fooservice.Model;
          context.params.sequelize = {
             include: [{
               model: AssociatedModel
               // normal Sequelize where query here
              }]
          };
          // delete any special query params so they are not used
          // in the WHERE clause in the db query.
          delete context.params.query.include;
       }

       return Promise.resolve(context);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. correct me if im wrong, but if im including participants in events this gonna give me filtered participants instead of events? this basically says events include participants where *some query*... but instead i want to get events where *one of participants is current user*

Comment: Try writing the query directly with just Sequelize as shown in the [Testing queries in isolation chapter](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#testing-sequelize-queries-in-isolation). After that it usually makes much more sense how to integrate it into the hook.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @daff 's answer I found my solution like this... Error that I was getting can be found [here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize/issues/248).

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

function includeBefore(hook) {
  currUserId = hook.params.user.id;
  userModel = hook.app.services.users.Model
  hook.params.sequelize = {
    where: {
      $or: [
        {
          creatorId: currUserId
        },
        {
          '$participants.id$': currUserId  //no idea what are '$$' for but it made it work
        }
      ]
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: userModel,
        as: 'creator',
      }, {
        model: userModel,
        as: 'participants',
        duplicating: false //fixed error that I was getting 
      }
    ],
  }
  return hook;
}


module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [
      authenticate('jwt'),
      hook => includeBefore(hook)
    ],
.........
```